# In if condition alert values are not get in the next div using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```html
<html>
<style>
.btn-bed{
     line-height: 25px !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    /* border: none !important; */
    width: 130px !important;
    font-family: Gill Sans MT Pro !important;
}
#mySelect{
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
#Select{
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
button#showdiv1:focus
{
 background-color: #357ebd;
    color: #fff;
}
.checked{
     color: white;
    background-color: #0077b9 !important;
}
.btn:focus {
  background-color: #ffff !important;
}
.dimension 
 {
   display: none;
 }
 
 .radio-buttons
 {
  display:none;
 }
 input[type=radio] + label
 {
  display:inline-block;
  <!--padding: 4px 12px; -->
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333;
  }
 input[type=radio]:checked + label
 {
  background-image: none;
  background-color:#0077b9 !important;
  color:#ffff;
 }
 #image-plainpattern{
 width:50px ! important;
 }
  li.selected { 
border:1px solid red;
 }
 .bed-di-btn{
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333;
 }

</style>
<body>
<form method="POST" id="dimension">      
 <div  id='div3'>
   <div class="col-md-12 container" >
      <div class='row'>
       <div class="col-md-7 step-function">
               <div class="form-group ">
         <label class="one-step" >Step Three:Choose Dimension</label>
         </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
           <label class="radio-inline btn-radio"><input type="radio" name="size" value="v" >Choose From Standard Size</label>
        <label class="radio-inline btn-radio"> <input type="radio" name="size" checked="checked" value="s"/>Enter Your Own Size</label>
        </div>
        
       <!-- enter your own size --> 
          <div class='row desc' id="sizes" >
              <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="own-size">Your Own sizes(in Inches)</label>
        </div>
         <form  id="lengthform" name="samplecode" method="POST">
          <div class="col-md-12 ">
        
         <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-3 text"><input type="text" name="length"  id="length" class="form-control len-class" Placeholder='Length'></div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-3  text"> <input type="text"  name="breadth" id="breadth" class="form-control len-class" Placeholder='Breadth'>
                 </div>
           <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-10">
            <p>(sizes can be between 48" to 84" Length <br>
                                                  and 24" to 78" breadth)</p> 
           
           </div>
         
        
         
         </div>
         </form>
        <div class="col-md-12 ">
         <label class="not-sure-matters" >Not sure how to measure your mattress?</label>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-12 ">
         <a href='#' class='link-find-out'>Click here to find out</a>
        </div>

       </div>
       <!-- END your own size --> 
       <!-- enter your Standard  size -->  
       <div class='row desc' id="sizev" style='Display:none;' >
              <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="own-size">Bed Type</label>
            <div class='custom-btn-grp'>
         <div class="bed_type">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
           <li> 
            <input type="radio" id="b1"  name="radios"  class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn" value="Single" checked >
            <label for="b1">Single</label>
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="b2" name="radios" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn"  value="Double" >
            <label for="b2">Double(Twin)</label>
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="b3" name="radios" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn"  value="Queen" >
            <label for="b3">Queen</label>
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="b4" name="radios" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn"  value="King" >
            <label for="b4">King</label>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
           <label class="own-size">Dimension</label>
           <div class='custom-btn-grp dimension-group'>
         <div  class ="dimension" id="d1">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
           <li> 
            <input type="radio" id="single1"  class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn className"  name="single" value="72*30" >
            <label for="single1">72x30</label>
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="single2" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn className"   name="single" checked value="72*36" >
            <label for="single2">72x36 </label>
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="single3" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn className"  name="single" value="75*36" >
            <label for="single3">75x36</label>
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="single4" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn className"  name="single" value="78*36" >
            <label for="single4">78x36</label>
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="single5"  class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn className"  name="single" value="84*36" >
            <label for="single5">84x36</label>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <div class ="dimension" id="d2">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="doubles1" class="radio-buttons className"  name="doubles" checked value="72*48" >
            <label for="doubles1">72x48</label>
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="doubles2" class="radio-buttons className"  name="doubles" value="75*48" >
            <label for="doubles2">75x48</label>
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="doubles3" class="radio-buttons className"  name="doubles" value="78*48" >
            <label for="doubles3">78x48</label>
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="doubles4" class="radio-buttons className"  name="doubles" value="84*48" >
            <label for="84x48">84x48</label>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <div  class ="dimension" id="d3">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="queen1" class="radio-buttons className"  name="queen"  checked value="72*60" >
            <label for="queen1">72x60</label>
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="queen2" class="radio-buttons className"  name="queen" value="75*60" >
            <label for="queen2">75x60</label>
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="queen3" class="radio-buttons className"  name="queen" value="78*60">
            <label for="queen3">78x60</label>
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="queen4"  class="radio-buttons className"  name="queen" value="84*60">
            <label for="queen4">84x60</label>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <div class ="dimension" id="d4">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="king1"  class="radio-buttons className"  name="king" checked value="72*72" >
            <label for="king1">72x72</label>
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="king2" class="radio-buttons className"  name="king" value="75*72" >
            <label for="king2">75x72</label>
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="king3" class="radio-buttons className"  name="king" value="3000k" >
            <label for="king3">78x72</label>
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="radio" id="king4" class="radio-buttons className"  name="king" value="84*72" >
            <label for="king4">84x72</label>
           </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 "><label class="not-sure-matters" >Not sure how to measure your mattress?</label></div>
         <div class="col-md-12 "><a href='#' class='link-find-out'>Click here to find out</a></div>
       </div>
        <!-- End standard sizes --> 
      </div>
       
        <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <img class="cust-image-size" src='img/cust.jpg'>
          </div>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div> 
    <div class='col-md-7'>
      <div class='pull-right'>
            <a href='#' id='summer5' class='next-color'>Next &#10095&#10095;</a>
          </div>
         <div class=' pull-left' >
             <a href='#Pre' id='summer4' class='next-color'><span>&#10094&#10094;</span>Previous </a>
       </div>
     </div>
     </div>
  </form>
  
  <div id="div4" style="display:none;"> <p id="demo"> </p></div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).load(function()
   {
   $('.dimension').hide();
   $('#d1').show();
   });
  $("input[name$='size']").click(function() {
   var test = $(this).val();
   //alert(test);
   $("div.desc").hide();
   $("#size" + test).show();
   if (test == 'v')
   {
   $('.bed_type ul li ').click(function()
      {
   var i = $(this).index();
   $('.dimension').hide();
   $('#d' + (i+1)).show();
   var type  ='b' + (i+1);
   document.getElementById(type).addEventListener("click", bedtype);
       });
   $('.dimension ul li').click(function () {
   var i = $(this).index();
   var single  ='single' + (i+1);
   //alert(single);
   var doubles  ='doubles' + (i+1);
   var queen  ='queen' + (i+1);
   var king  ='king' + (i+1);

   document.getElementById(single).addEventListener("click", price);
   document.getElementById(doubles).addEventListener("click", price);
   document.getElementById(queen).addEventListener("click", price);
   document.getElementById(king).addEventListener("click", price);
   

   });
   function price() 
   {
   var price_btn=this.id;

   var price_value = document.getElementById(price_btn).value;
   var arr = price_value.split('*');

   var bed1= arr[0];
   alert(bed1);
   var bed2= arr[1];
   $("#length").val(bed1);
   $("#breadth").val(bed2);
   }
  
   }
     else(test =='s')
   {
   $("#length").change(function(){
   var length =$(this).val();
   $("#breadth").change(function(){
   var breadth =$(this).val();
   //var lenbre= length * breadth;
   //alert(lenbre);
   var result =length.concat(breadth);
   var len = (length * breadth) ;
   });
   });
   }
          });
   $('#dimension').validate({
   rules: {
   length: {
   required: true,
   number: true,
   range: [48, 84]
   },
   breadth: {
   required: true,
   number: true,
   range: [24, 78]
   }
   },
   messages: {

   length: {
   required: 'Please select a template'
   },
   breadth: {
   required: 'Please select a template'
   }
   },
   submitHandler: function(){
   $('div[id ^=div]').hide();
   $("#div4").show();
    var data = $(this.currentForm).serialize();
     $("#demo").text(data +'"');
        return false;
   }

   });
   $("#summer5").click(function() {
   $("#dimension").submit();
   });
   });
  
 

</script>
</html>
```

I am choosing only one radio button to enter the value are get alert to next div.I am getting alert error like this

**Error:**

> 0*[object HTMLInputElement]

**My result:**

the value of  the length is shown not message only value: **74**

the value of the breadth is shown not message only value : **78**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.dimension').hide();
    $('#d1').show();
  });
  $("input[name$='size']").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).val();
    //alert(test);
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("#size" + test).show();
    if (test == 'v') {
      $('.bed_type ul li ').click(function() {
        var i = $(this).index();
        $('.dimension').hide();
        $('#d' + (i + 1)).show();
        var type = 'b' + (i + 1);
        document.getElementById(type).addEventListener("click", bedtype);
      });
      $('.dimension ul li').click(function() {
        var i = $(this).index();
        var single = 'single' + (i + 1);
        //alert(single);
        var doubles = 'doubles' + (i + 1);
        var queen = 'queen' + (i + 1);
        var king = 'king' + (i + 1);

        document.getElementById(single).addEventListener("click", price);
        document.getElementById(doubles).addEventListener("click", price);
        document.getElementById(queen).addEventListener("click", price);
        document.getElementById(king).addEventListener("click", price);


      });

      function price() {
        var price_btn = this.id;

        var price_value = document.getElementById(price_btn).value;
        var arr = price_value.split('*');

        var bed1 = arr[0];
        alert(bed1);
        var bed2 = arr[1];
        $("#length").val(bed1);
        $("#breadth").val(bed2);
      }

    } else(test == 's') {
      $("#length").change(function() {
        var length = $(this).val();
        $("#breadth").change(function() {
          var breadth = $(this).val();
          //var lenbre= length * breadth;
          //alert(lenbre);
          var result = length.concat(breadth);
          var len = (length * breadth);
        });
      });
    }
  });
  $('#dimension').validate({
    rules: {
      length: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        range: [48, 84]
      },
      breadth: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        range: [24, 78]
      }
    },
    messages: {

      length: {
        required: 'Please select a template'
      },
      breadth: {
        required: 'Please select a template'
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
      $('div[id ^=div]').hide();
      $("#div4").show();
      var data = $(this.currentForm).serialize();
     $("#demo").text(data +'"');
      return false;
    }

  });
  $("#summer5").click(function() {
    $("#dimension").submit();
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-bed {
  line-height: 25px !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  /* border: none !important; */
  width: 130px !important;
  font-family: Gill Sans MT Pro !important;
}
#mySelect {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
#Select {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
button#showdiv1:focus {
  background-color: #357ebd;
  color: #fff;
}
.checked {
  color: white;
  background-color: #0077b9 !important;
}
.btn:focus {
  background-color: #ffff !important;
}
.dimension {
  display: none;
}
.radio-buttons {
  display: none;
}
input[type=radio] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  <!--padding: 4px 12px;
  --> border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #0077b9 !important;
  color: #ffff;
}
#image-plainpattern {
  width: 50px ! important;
}
li.selected {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.bed-di-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" id="dimension">
  <div id='div3'>
    <div class="col-md-12 container">
      <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-md-7 step-function">
          <div class="form-group ">
            <label class="one-step">Step Three:Choose Dimension</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="radio-inline btn-radio">
              <input type="radio" name="size" value="v">Choose From Standard Size</label>
            <label class="radio-inline btn-radio">
              <input type="radio" name="size" checked="checked" value="s" />Enter Your Own Size</label>
          </div>

          <!-- enter your own size -->
          <div class='row desc' id="sizes">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <label class="own-size">Your Own sizes(in Inches)</label>
            </div>
            <form id="lengthform" name="samplecode" method="POST">
              <div class="col-md-12 ">

                <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-3 text">
                  <input type="text" name="length" id="length" class="form-control len-class" Placeholder='Length'>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-3  text">
                  <input type="text" name="breadth" id="breadth" class="form-control len-class" Placeholder='Breadth'>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-10">
                  <p>(sizes can be between 48" to 84" Length
                    <br>and 24" to 78" breadth)</p>

                </div>



              </div>
            </form>
            <div class="col-md-12 ">
              <label class="not-sure-matters">Not sure how to measure your mattress?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 ">
              <a href='#' class='link-find-out'>Click here to find out</a>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- END your own size -->
          <!-- enter your Standard  size -->
          <div class='row desc' id="sizev" style='Display:none;'>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <label class="own-size">Bed Type</label>
              <div class='custom-btn-grp'>
                <div class="bed_type">
                  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="b1" name="radios" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn" value="Single" checked>
                      <label for="b1">Single</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="b2" name="radios" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn" value="Double">
                      <label for="b2">Double(Twin)</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="b3" name="radios" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn" value="Queen">
                      <label for="b3">Queen</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="b4" name="radios" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn" value="King">
                      <label for="b4">King</label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <label class="own-size">Dimension</label>
              <div class='custom-btn-grp dimension-group'>
                <div class="dimension" id="d1">
                  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="single1" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn className" name="single" value="72*30">
                      <label for="single1">72x30</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="single2" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn className" name="single" checked value="72*36">
                      <label for="single2">72x36</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="single3" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn className" name="single" value="75*36">
                      <label for="single3">75x36</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="single4" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn className" name="single" value="78*36">
                      <label for="single4">78x36</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="single5" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn className" name="single" value="84*36">
                      <label for="single5">84x36</label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="dimension" id="d2">
                  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="doubles1" class="radio-buttons className" name="doubles" checked value="72*48">
                      <label for="doubles1">72x48</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="doubles2" class="radio-buttons className" name="doubles" value="75*48">
                      <label for="doubles2">75x48</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="doubles3" class="radio-buttons className" name="doubles" value="78*48">
                      <label for="doubles3">78x48</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="doubles4" class="radio-buttons className" name="doubles" value="84*48">
                      <label for="84x48">84x48</label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="dimension" id="d3">
                  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="queen1" class="radio-buttons className" name="queen" checked value="72*60">
                      <label for="queen1">72x60</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="queen2" class="radio-buttons className" name="queen" value="75*60">
                      <label for="queen2">75x60</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="queen3" class="radio-buttons className" name="queen" value="78*60">
                      <label for="queen3">78x60</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="queen4" class="radio-buttons className" name="queen" value="84*60">
                      <label for="queen4">84x60</label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="dimension" id="d4">
                  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="king1" class="radio-buttons className" name="king" checked value="72*72">
                      <label for="king1">72x72</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="king2" class="radio-buttons className" name="king" value="75*72">
                      <label for="king2">75x72</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="king3" class="radio-buttons className" name="king" value="3000k">
                      <label for="king3">78x72</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="radio" id="king4" class="radio-buttons className" name="king" value="84*72">
                      <label for="king4">84x72</label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 ">
              <label class="not-sure-matters">Not sure how to measure your mattress?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 "><a href='#' class='link-find-out'>Click here to find out</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End standard sizes -->
        </div>

        <div class='row'>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <img class="cust-image-size" src='img/cust.jpg'>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-7'>
      <div class='pull-right'>
        <a href='#' id='summer5' class='next-color'>Next &#10095&#10095;</a>
      </div>
      <div class=' pull-left'>
        <a href='#Pre' id='summer4' class='next-color'><span>&#10094&#10094;</span>Previous </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

    <div id="div4" style="display:none;"> <p id="demo"> </p></div>
```

Comment: there is a lot of code here, so which bit is the problem specifically? There are 4 different alerts, is just one of them the issue?

Comment: you enter the value in length and breadth click next you see the result.in result only entered value should be display in next div

Comment: there are two snippets now in your question. which is the right one? They don't seem to run in the page - nothing is displayed when pressing Run Code Snippet. I think the snippet engine is down. can you make a JSFiddle instead?

Comment: 1st u run code snippets u get idea.what exact i want Get the result but i am

Comment: that's what I'm saying. I can't run the snippets - it's not working on this site right now (at least not for me anyway). So maybe once it's fixed I can have a look. Or if you want a faster response put it in some other site like JSFiddle